# Phone interrupted during first charge, battery damage?

Tags: battery, charging

Got my new Sony Xperia Go and after draining its initial power, plugged it in to charge. Red light was on, but the battery icon did not show that it was busy charging.

So I unplugged it and reconnected. Now the green light is on and the phone shows 100% charged. This is impossible as it was only plugged in for a few seconds.

Did I just destroy my battery?? It's plugged in now with a green light showing. Is it charging?